# how to set Datatable plugin for my php table

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

i'm new in jquery and i have a probleme when trinig to show searche field and organisation butom of the pluginwiche to integrate datatable in my source code, and i'm not sure of integration of js and css file link.

here is my source code of table

```
     <div class="table responsive ">
      <table id="datatable" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover no-margin display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
        <thead>
        <tr class="table-danger">
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prenom</th>
            <th>Structure</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date rec</th>
            <th>RC</th>
            <th>Matricule</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

    <?php 

    if (strcmp($affectation,'DSI')==0)  
        {

            while($query2=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
            {
            echo "<tbody><tr><td>".$query2['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query2['prenom']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query2['affectation']."</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"col-xs\">".$query2['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query2['date_rec']."</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"text-DANGER\">".$query2['nbr_rc']." Jours</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query2['matricule']."</td>";
            echo "<td> <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs green pull-center\" href='aff_emp.php?sessId=$sessId&id=".$query2['id']."'>Afficher </a></td>";
            }

        }

    else
            {

            while($query4=mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
            {
            echo "<tbody><tr><td>".$query4['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query4['prenom']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query4['affectation']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query4['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query4['date_rec']."</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"text-DANGER\">".$query4['nbr_rc']." Jours</td>";
            echo "<td>".$query4['matricule']."</td>";
            echo "<td> <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs green pull-center\" href='edit.php?sessId=$sessId&id=".$query4['id']."'>Modifier</a></td>";
            echo "<td> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs green btn-primary disabled pull-center\">Supp</button> ";
            echo "<td> <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs green pull-center\" href='aff_emp.php?sessId=$sessId&id=".$query4['id']."'>Afficher </a></td>";
            }

    }

    ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

tks in advance
and source javascript of function datatable

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Application gestion de RC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#datatable').dataTable();
    });

    </script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Case Sensitive

Has nothing to do with php...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').dataTable();
});
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();
});
```

Note the upper case **D**ataTable();

use your developer tools or firebug to see the javascript console so you can see errors like this.

## Examle

check out this [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyMmmR) on codepen.io

Comment: +1. Don't forget that it requires a well formed `<tbody></tbody>` tag. OP did not close their `</tbody>` and should also not put the opening `<tbody>` tag within their loop.

Comment: I think he is asking if he could place the search field at the bottom of the table.

Comment: the OP text is unclear he said 'butom' which I thought was 'button'.  He also questioned 'integration of js and css file link' which I thought implied he was not able to get datatables to work at all

Answer (score 0):

move the  outside the while loop .. and move the  inside the while loop

so

```
tbody
while{
<tr>
<td><td>
...
</tr>
}
<tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatables lets you position its elements like the sarchbox, its relatively easy, you can take a look here. https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html